# How to extend NSProgressIndicator and increase size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I need to extend NSProgressIndicator and increase it's size. So far I've created a Custom Class and have implemented the following code as override of `drawRect:`

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    dirtyRect.size = NSMakeSize(98.0f, 98.0f);
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

But I'm not getting any difference when the control is drawn. Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0):

along with your overridden drawRect, try adding following to your subclass:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
}
```

Comment: What could this possibly have to do with the problem in question?